# php script does not include file when called from within a subdirectory

Tags: php

> Edit: The problem was in a `array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir')` in the
>   included file. The file was being included, but there was no output.

I have the following two scripts:

http://exampletld/mrrobot/mrobotseason1.php:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
print $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
echo ini_get('open_basedir');
include("/var/www/virtual/exampletld/episodes/htdocs/dirs.php"); 
?>
```

http://exampletld/testinc.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include("/var/www/virtual/exampletld/episodes/htdocs/dirs.php"); 
?>
```

The second script gives the expected output, by including dirs.php. In the first script, however, dirs.php is not included at all. I have checked and verified ownership for the files, and permissions. They're all the same. The only difference seems to be that the first script is in a subdirectory relative to the second. However I am referring to the included php file by its full path.

I have checked apache server logs. There are no errors shown. The second script (which executes properly in the webserver root), if copied to the directory containing the first script, fails to include the php file.

`open_basedir` is `/var/www/virtual/exampletld/:/usr/share/php/`

Why would they have different results when executed?

Comment: I see you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` did you get any errors? try `ini_set(display_errors,1);` as well

Comment: I set that as well. There are no errors/warnings reported by the webserver.

Comment: that's strange i would think that include would at least provide a warning if it failed. perhaps try require instead of include, oh and also the parens are not needed with include. try `include "/var/www/virtual/exampletld/episodes/htdocs/dirs.php";`

Comment: require and omitting the parentheses has the same effect. I tried running it from bash. If I execute it from within the subdirectory, the file is not included. However if I execute the same file while staying in the root directory, it does get included.

Comment: It makes no sense that you're not getting any errors output. The only things I can think think of are: you're running the script as a different virtual user and the chrooted home dir is not where you think it is. or: you're redirecting stderr from bash to a file or /dev/null and therefore not seeing it

Comment: Unfortunately those scenarios arent true. I am running the scripts as the same user. The same script works in the parent directory, but not in the sub directory. I'm thinking this is some php.ini restriction, but can't find one.